# How to create common layout for all pages, with render some data from server on header with getStaticProps in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, next.js

I want to create a common header and footer in the next js

But in the header I am fetching a List of category from the server by using getStaticProps(), & as next js getStaticProps work as a page, not as a component,

So how can show that data

I tried as a component which works but, It was like client-side render but I don't want client-side render I want server-side render data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would look into `getInitialProps` in custom [Custom Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#customizing-renderpage).